# How to get permission of file and folder for specific user?

Tags: permissions

I want add file and folder in tree view control for specific user  if he has permission to access  that file and folder.
I want to get permission of file or folder to check current user can access that file or folder in share point client object model.

Answer (score 2):

To check permissions to a list or library:

```
list.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems);
```

To check a list item its the same

```
item.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems)
```

To check a folder you do the check in the list item object of the folder:

```
folder.Item.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems)
```

Replace **.AddListItems** with **.Open** if you just want to check if they have read rights.

If you want to get the current user before elevating you code and iterating through content then the command is:

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
```